# Implementing Gateway causing Problems in Message Flow

Tags: spring-integration

I have a scenario in which i am receiving a message and routing it to different message channels using Recipient-list-router.

```
<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="inputChannel1" 
    apply-sequence="true"   id="router1">
  <int:recipient channel="service1" />
  <int:recipient channel="service2" />
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

---

This aggregator is used to aggregate the response from above 2 services and    redirects the aggregated output to some other channel for further processing.

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregator1" output-channel="channel2" >
    <bean class="wsintg.service.AggregatorClass" /> 
</int:aggregator>
```

---

The code for individual services looks like this :

```
 <!--service 1 code -->

<int:service-activator input-channel="service1" ref="service1Ref" />

    <int:gateway id="service1Ref" default-request-channel="success_channel" error-channel="error_channel" />

    <int:chain id="chainid1" input-channel="success_channel" output-channel="aggregator1">
        step 1 :xsl transformation 
        step 2 :call to a service using ws:outbound-gateway
            <int:service-activator id="sa1">
                <bean class="samplePkg.returnMessage"></bean>   <!--return message simply returns the message without doing anything -->
            </int:service-activator>    
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain id="chainid2" input-channel="error_channel" output-channel="aggregator1" >
                <int:service-activator>
                    <!-- some custom exception handling -->
                </int:service-activator>
    </int:chain>

    <!--service 2 code -->   same as service 1
```

---

1. Problem :

   1. If i don't use gateway in Service 1 and Service 2 and simply do the transformations, the code works perfectly.
   2. But, as i need to do some error handling using error_channel, so i put a gateway in service1 and service 2 code. Now the flow
      stucks after service activator in service 1 without throwing any
      exception.          and does not calls the service 2 flow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show real configuration, not just comments; we can't guess what your application looks like.

That said, you can't just send error messages to the aggregator because the aggregation information is in the `failedMessage` headers and needs to be promoted.

See [error handling in this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/barrier) for an example.

As always, the first step to debug situations like this is to turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` and follow the messages through the flow.

You will usually be able to determine the problem that way.